# how to add custom wordpress Menu using just A tag output

Tags: wordpress, menu, themes

I want to create menu like below code but wordpress generate other code.
help me to generate code like below HTML code 
Thanks in advance.
[image]

help me to generate below code using wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
add_theme_support('menu');
function register_newtheme_menu(){
    register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'main-menu'=>_('Main Menu')
            )
    );
    
}

add_action('init','register_newtheme_menu');







function add_menuclass($ulclass) {
   return preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="navigation-link w-nav-link" ', $ulclass);
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','add_menuclass');
?>
```

```html
<nav class="menu-hamburger w-nav-menu" role="navigation">
            <?php    
             $defaults = array(
              'container'       => 'false', 
              'echo'            => false,
              'fallback_cb'     => false,
              //'items_wrap'      => '<a id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
              'depth'           => 0
              );
                //echo wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
              echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $defaults ),'<a>');
          ?>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using menu walker class like this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
        'container' => false,
        'menu' => 'main-menu',
        'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar_menu',
        'walker'         => new Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu
        )
    );
```

Comment: how to add custom classes to <a>

Comment: Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu function not found

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu' not found